# Dataframe Read CSV - Delimiter Not Working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am attempting to read a CSV via Pandas. The code works fine but the result does not properly separate the data. Below is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', encoding='utf-16', sep='\\', error_bad_lines=False)
df.loc[:3]
```

When I run this the output looks something like this:

[image]

Anything I can do to adjust this? All help is appreciated!

Comment: If the data is tab-separated, you'll need to use: `sep='\t'`. Voting to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use \t as sep argument while reading csv file

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data="""id\tname\temail
1\tJohn\tjohn@example.com
2\tJoe\tjoe@example.com
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),sep="\t")
```

- id    name    email
- 1 John    john@example.com
- 2 Joe joe@example.com

*you dont need IO, its just for example.*

Comment: Appreciate the quick response! This worked like charm